# In a minimax algorithm for naughts and crosses, what are nodes stored as?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I'm a beginner to java, so feel free to correct any of my phrasing of this question.

Anyway, I'm working on creating a naughts and crosses/ tic tac toe game with a perfect AI opponent, and I aim to use an alpha-beta pruning minimax algorithm. I think I understand the algorithm quite well, but I can't work out how to incorporate the 'nodes' and 'nodeChilds' into it. Here is the algorithhm as found on wikipedia, in pseudocode.

```
01 function minimax(node, depth, maximizingPlayer)
02     if depth = 0 or node is a terminal node
03         return the heuristic value of node

04     if maximizingPlayer
05         bestValue := −∞
06         for each child of node
07             v := minimax(child, depth − 1, FALSE)
08             bestValue := max(bestValue, v)
09         return bestValue

10     else    (* minimizing player *)
11         bestValue := +∞
12         for each child of node
13             v := minimax(child, depth − 1, TRUE)
14             bestValue := min(bestValue, v)
15         return bestValue
```

Could anyone offer any insight into what kind of value the 'node' should have? In the algorithm I currently have, i call the minimax function like this:

```
game.minimax(0, 1); //1 represents the computer's turn, equivalent to maximizingPlayer 

public int minimax(int depth, int turn)
```

Any help/ explanation would be vastly appreciated, so apologies if I've given insufficient information or explained my problem badly.

Comment: Note that the pseudo-code you posted doesn't show alpha-beta pruning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node` is a state of the game tree. In the case of naughts and crosses, it depicts the current state of the board. The minimax algorithm needs a node that has the following information:

1. if it's a terminal node (end of the game)
2. the next player to play
3. the value, or utility of the node, to rate it against other nodes. You'll need a heuristic value for non-terminal boards.
4. the possible next nodes (children) from this node

You could create a `Node` interface with that information and use it to create a generic minimax implementation. Something like this:

```
enum Player { MAX, MIN }

interface Node {
  boolean isTerminal();
  int utility();
  Player nextPlayer();
  List<Node> children();
}
```

Then, you'd have a naughts and crosses implementation for `Node` that codifies the rules of the game. You can store the board as a simple array of 9 integers (0 for empty space, 1 for X, 2 for O), for example.

```
class NaughtsAndCrossesNode implements Node {
  private int[] board;

  // ....
}
```

What's important to realize is that any `Node` implementation should be an *immutable* class. Playing the game (getting a node's children) creates more instances, and doesn't change the existing ones.

Comment: Thankyou. So could you give a kind of example of what value it might take? I can understand that it depicts the current state of the board, but in what way? If that makes sense.

Comment: Added some more info

Comment: It depends on how you implement the board. It could be a simple array of 9 integers, 0 for empty space, 1 for X, 2 for O.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it entirely, now :) - also to your comment about the pseudocode not showing alpha beta pruning, I was just using that pseudocode as an easier example, but you're right. Is alpha-beta pruning difficult to implement?

Comment: Not really, it's just another twist to the algorithm. There's also some pseudo-code in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning).